# How are stored procedures called and executed in asp.NET webforms?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, webforms

I'm wondering if when a stored procedure is called within a webform, does it call it like 'EXEC [dbo].[StoredProcedure]' with the passed parameters and then sends back its response data? Does it work that way or not?

Comment: why don't you run the `profiler` and see for yourself

Comment: @Squirrel ooo, okay I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question, and don't edit the title to say ANSWERED: you can add you own answer to you question, and in a few days you can mark it as the accepted answer. As it stands, StackOverflow will list this as an unanswered question.

Comment: @Richardissimo okie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as Squirrel suggested, I ran the Profiler and got the answer I wanted. My guess was right, it does call it by the EXEC command as we can see in the screenshot I took from the Profiler.
[image]